# R Shiny only runs the UI part of my code but not the server function part

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am creating a shiny application on the data set "CO2" (Carbon Dioxide Uptake in Grass Plant) and wanted to make a scatterplot of carbon concentration vs uptake rate. My goal is to update the plot based on the type of treatment the plant received and update the x-limit of the plot (concentration level) using the slider input.

When I highlighted the entire code below and run it

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage( # ui controls the layout of the page 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h2("Carbon Dioxide Uptake in Grass Plants"),
      selectInput(inputID = "treatment", label = "Treatment: ", 
                  choices = c("nonchilled", "chilled"), selected = "nonchilled"
      ),
      sliderInput(inputID = "slider", label = "Concentration limit:",
                  min = 0, max = max(CO2$conc), value = 500, step = 100)
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("scatterplot"), 
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){ # server instructs how to build app
  filteredData <- reactive({
    subset(CO2, Treatment == input$treatment)
  })
  
  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(filteredData, aes(x = conc, y = uptake), main = "scatter plot") + 
      geom_point(alpha=0.5) +
      xlim(0,input$slider) 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I got the error message

```
Error in selectInput(inputID = "treatment", label = "Treatment: ", choices = c("nonchilled",  : 
  unused argument (inputID = "treatment")
```

I believed the cause of the error is that R only runs the code up to the end of the ui part and never get to the server function, because my console look like this:

```
> library(shiny)
> library(ggplot2)
> 
>  
> 
> ui <- fluidPage( # ui controls the layout of the page 
+   sidebarLayout(
+     sidebarPanel(
+       h2("Carbon Dioxide Uptake in Grass Plants"),
+       selectInput(inputID = "treatment", label = "Treatment: ", 
+                   choices = c("nonchilled", "chilled"), selected = "nonchilled"
+       ),
+       sliderInput(inputID = "slider", label = "Concentration limit:",
+                   min = 0, max = max(CO2$conc), value = 500, step = 100)
+     ),
+     
+     mainPanel(
+       plotOutput("scatterplot"), 
+     )
+   )
+ )
```

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a capitalization problem. In the `selectInput()` function it's inputId not inputID. This should work:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage( # ui controls the layout of the page 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h2("Carbon Dioxide Uptake in Grass Plants"),
      selectInput(inputId = "treatment", label = "Treatment: ", 
                  choices = c("nonchilled", "chilled"), selected = "nonchilled"
      ),
      sliderInput(inputId = "slider", label = "Concentration limit:",
                  min = 0, max = max(CO2$conc), value = 500, step = 100)
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("scatterplot"), 
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){ # server instructs how to build app
  filteredData <- reactive({
    subset(CO2, Treatment == input$treatment)
  })
  
  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(filteredData, aes(x = conc, y = uptake), main = "scatter plot") + 
      geom_point(alpha=0.5) +
      xlim(0,input$slider) 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```